# Xpath which includes the attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML:

```
<log> 
  <xplmsg logdate="31-03-11 23:30:55" > 
    <schema> 
      <infopairs> 
        <info name="device"  value="Blah Humidity" ></info> 
        <info name="type"  value="humidity" ></info> 
      </infopairs> 
    </schema> 
  </xplmsg> 
</log>
```

What xPath would return:

```
  <xplmsg logdate="31-03-11 23:30:55" > 
    <schema> 
      <infopairs> 
        <info name="device"  value="Blah Humidity" ></info> 
        <info name="type"  value="humidity" ></info> 
      </infopairs> 
    </schema> 
  </xplmsg>
```

Including logdate="31-03-11 23:30:55"

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
/log/xplmsg[@logdate = '31-03-11 23:30:55']
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Alejandro's answer is correct, **there is even simpler XPath expression** that selects exactly the wanted element:

```
/*/xplmsg
```

**or even**:

```
/*/*
```

This is due to the fact that in the provided XML document the top element has a single child element -- and in this case it is not necessary to specify specific attribute name/value or even the name of the element that we want to be selected.

In case you want all of the nodes of the `xplmsg` subtree to be selected, then use this XPath expression:

```
/*/xplmsg//@*  |   /*/xplmsg//node()
```